# Unable to get Virtualhost config working with Apache 2.4.6

Tags: centos, virtualhost, apache-2.4

I had a HTTPS site running successfully under Apache 2.4.6 on CentOS7. I was then asked to host another site on the server, which at the moment is just HTTP but will eventually also move to HTTPS.
I followed the instructions [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-7) for setting up virtual hosts, but I am getting odd results.
So if I now visit https://www.domainA.co.uk, I get a "Page Cannot Be Displayed" and I cant work out why it is not dishing up the HTTPS page.

If I visit http://www.domainA.co.uk, I get the static landing page for http://www.domainB.co.uk.

Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing all the specs., I would say it is a DNS issue, so please check/verify DNS (both Public/External AND/OR Internal).

Comment: There is no external DNS for domainB yet. I was trying to get them set up right internally first.

Comment: - Mind posting your httpd.conf?!

Comment: A couple of other checks:
1. Make sure that you have added index.php to the DirectoryIndex directive in httpd.conf
2. Check permissions.
3. Make sure there's no errors in the config file (ie. extra spaces, etc.)
4. Other.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I went back to the httpd.conf file and somehow whilst transitioning to the Virtualhost setup, I had managed to remove the "Listen 0.0.0.0:443" from the httpd.conf, so Apache was never going to listen for inbound HTTPS. It's all sorted now. Many thanks.